# Gas efficiency of totalSupply() vs. a tokenID counter | ERC-721

Tags: ethereum, solidity, erc721

I'm creating a solidity contract for an NFT and in my `mint` function I'm not sure if a call to `totalSupply()` vs using a token counter and incrementing it is better practice. Does either variation cost more gas? Is one the more standard practice? I've seen examples of both being used.

Variation 1:

```
contract MyNFT is ERC721Enumerable, PaymentSplitter, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private currentTokenId;
...

function mint(uint256 _count)
        public payable
{
    uint256 tokenId = currentTokenId.current();
    require(tokenId < MAX_SUPPLY, "Max supply reached");
    for(uint i = 0; i < _count; ++i){
        currentTokenId.increment();
        uint256 newItemId = currentTokenId.current();
        _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
    }
}
}
```

Variation 2:

```
function mint(uint256 _count)
        public payable
{
    uint supply = totalSupply();
    require( supply + _count <= MAX_SUPPLY, "Exceeds max supply." );
    for(uint i = 0; i < _count; ++i){
        _safeMint(msg.sender, supply + i);
    }
}
```

Both versions seem to work. I just want to be sure I'm using the most efficient / secure. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Remix show the gas used when a function is called, just compare the gas usage. Similarly there plugins to measure gas consumption for Truffle and others tools.

Comment: Looping is not so efficient solution.  Without whole contract code base is hard to predict efficiency. You can try to analyze assembly of this contract

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I just started using remix and it's really helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off all, you need to show us the underlying implementations. However, I can speculate that these are unmodified openzeppelin implementations for [ERC721Enumerable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol) and [Counters](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/4a9cc8b4918ef3736229a5cc5a310bdc17bf759f/contracts/utils/Counters.sol).

*For your case only*, using `Counter` seems a little bit pointless to me.

1. It increases your deployment costs(just a little bit) because of redundant code coming from Counter library
2. You already know the length of your tokens array, why keep it twice? Counters is created for situations where you don't know the number of elements, like a mapping.

I am not guaranteeing correctness of the following analysis

Calling `totalSupply` (looking from opcode point of view) will:

- jump to totalsupply (8 gas)
- sload tokens.slot (200) gas

However, while using `Counter`, you `sstore` (>= 5000 gas) each time you decrement and `sload` (200 gas)  each time you read.

As long as i am not mistaken about Counter using storage, and therefore `sstore` and `sload` opcodes, second variant will use much less gas.

Comment: appreciate the answer, yes I'm using the generic openzeppelin implementations. This makes sense

Comment: This means totalSupply() is more efficient right